# Plot voltage gain in LTspice while ignoring output DC offset

Tags: ltspice

How can I plot voltage gain (Vout/Vin) when Vout can have some DC offset?

Comment: If you want to use `Vout/Vin`, then you'd better use the `.AC` analysis, but then you don't have or need DC offsets. If you want to use it in `.TRAN` (which is what it looks you're after), then you'd be better using DC quantities at the input (i.e. fixed, unipolar voltage), rather than alternating. Else, if the only thing in your way is the DC, then simply subtract `gain*DC` from the output, or add appropiate negative sign DC at the input.

Comment: The answer is: as you would do on a piece of paper. Subtract whatever you need to subtract and be happy. But I suspect you are trying to do something odd... Are you willing to share your circuit?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working in a simulation why not take the easiest approach. Add a capacitor from the output and connect the other side to a large size resistor that goes to GND. Then take your reading of output AC voltage across the large size resistor.